# DoubleClick event in p:dataTable

Tags: ajax, primefaces, datatable

I'm try add doubleClick ajax event to dataTable from PrimeFaces.  The error that display is " Event:dblClick is not supported"
How I can add the event to the component?

Comment: Why do you need the dblClick event on the dataTable? See page 173 of the 5.3 docs.Can't you use the rowDblSelect event?

Comment: I need this event for access to the content of folders or access to the document specific. 
I checked and PrimeFaces currently use 5.2, I'll update and try again. Thank you very much!

Comment: Folders are server side, nothing do do with a single or double click. Same for documents. Why do you need it on the datatable, what does it contain, where do you click on... Please try to be specific.

Comment: The table is a file browser and folders. Their help was very helpful, only changing the version of PrimeFaces it worked! Thank you!

Comment: _"Their help was very helpful,"_??? I don't understand?

Comment: It means that you helped me, thank you! 
My English is not good, sorry :)

Comment: ohh, ok. So you used rowDblSelect? Or did you use dblClick with a newer version.

Comment: Yes, I used rowDblSelect successfully!

Answer (score 0):

A nice approach could be adding the doubleClick event by jQuery as in http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_dblclick.asp :

```
   $("#myDataTableId").dblclick(function() {
        myDoubleClickCommand();
   });
```

And call a 'remoteCommand' from it, in order to reach out for the bean methods:

```
<p:remoteCommand name="myDoubleClickCommand"
                         action="#{myBean.myDoubleClickMethod()}"
                         autoRun="false"
                         partialSubmit="true"
                         process="@this" />
```

If trying this solution, keep in mind that every time you update the 'double clicked' element, it will be re-renderized. Therefore, the dbClick will be lost, so you will have to re-assing it each time you update it.